# May I ask this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'd like to know what bugs and feature request a user would experience if looking at my webapp. I have identified a few bugs and I'm looking for more bugs to be discovered (in a fairly complex webapp). Could I ask such a question or is there some other site where that type of question is ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not appropriate for this site.

- We don't allow site reviews
- We don't allow open ended questions (StackExchange software works best when there can be one "correct" answer)

I don' think there is a StackExchange site that would allow your question.   It sounds like you need to get some help with quality assurance (QA) for your webapp.